# Format entire Excel spreadsheet so there are only 3 digits after decimal points

Tags: microsoft-excel, format

If I have 3 that becomes 3.000. 4.5678 becomes 4.568. Is it possible to do this in excel without giving you the spreadsheet or giving you an reproducible example? I want to format  an entire Excel spreadsheet so there are only 3 digits after decimal points or figure out a way to fix the number of significant figures in every cell of the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to FORMAT the data, but not actually change the data, then the solution is a two part solution.

Part one is to apply the following format to all the cells with data. Taking Gary's Student's approach is perfectly fine to physically accomplish it. Here is the format to apply:

```
#,##0.###
```

With this, you get comma separators for the thousands and so on. Drop the leading `#` and the comma if that is not desired. Next, it ensures you get a leading `0` for values between 1 and -1 (so you would have " 0.123 " not " .123 "). If that is not desired, use another `#` instead of the `0` ( #,###.### not #,##0.### ).

The magic is in the fact that the `#` used after the decimal point causes 1 decimal place to occur for each one used `BUT ONLY` if that does not produce a string of `0's`. So a value like PI will give 3.142 and a value like 5.202384 will give 5.202 (it realizes the `0` in there is necessary because there are more non-zero decimal places after it) but a value like 28.2 will give just that, not 28.200, because it sees those last two `0's` are just fluff.

Bear in mind, it is NOT NOT NOT following any rules at all about `significant figures`. It is only deciding what to display.

However... it has an ugly effect. A number like 324 will display a decimal point after it like so:  "324."  which no one likes. So what to do? After all, that's the only actual problem at this point.

That's part two of the solution. Apply conditional formatting to the same highlighted cells. Set it up to work from a formula and use this formula:

```
=(TRUNC(A1,0)=A1)
```

(This assumes the active cell ("highlighted cell") is A1. If not, use whatever the actual cell is.)

Notice that there are NO `$` characters in that address:  A1 not, say, $A$1 . This is important. If you have the active cell as A1 and use the formula above, it will actually test each cell against itself which is what you want.

The formula cuts off the value in the cell at its decimal point and compares that result to the actual value in the cell. So if it is an integer, they are equal and it knows to apply the format here to keep that nasty decimal point from appearing. If the actual value is not an integer, the test gives FALSE and it lets the regular format from part one be used showing up to three decimal places.

After entering the formula, you have to set a format. But it's exactly like you want right now, so click on the format button, then click on OK, and you're done. Poeple sometimes tell me it did not work for their version of Excel, and if so for you, apply the custom numerical format of:

General;General;General;General

and that WILL work. So try the easy one first, then do that only if needed. Or just do it. What the heck, eh?

Save the conditional formatting work and you're done.

(This seems involved but it's only because I explained what the steps do. In reality, there are just two short formatting operations to perform, one regular, one in conditional formatting `so it is quite quick and easy to do.`)

Comment: how do I apply =(TRUNC(A1,0)=A1) to not only A1 but also the entire spreadsheet?

Comment: Assume A1=567. Do I replace the value of A1 with =(TRUNC(567,0)=567) then drag to cover the entire spreadsheet that is non-empty?

Answer (score 1):

Select the entire worksheet and apply the desired format:

[image]

*(you could accomplish the same thing with a VBA macro.)*

Comment: I now have a spreadsheet with cells that on average have less significant figures. There's a lot of numbers that have an excessive number of signiicant figures, i.e. 324 became 324.000. How do I make all the numbers that are 324.000 or 432.000 go back to 432 or 324 without undoing the progress I made, i.e. 3.1415926 remains 3.142?

Comment: @Lasuiqw  Let me think about it.